# Text doesn't wrap with position absolute

Tags: html, css

I have the following to put text overlay image:

```css
    #about{
        padding-top: 70px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .image{
        background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/about.webp');
        background-position: 50% 30%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70vh;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        filter: brightness(80%);
    }
    .content{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;
        direction: rtl;
        width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<section id="about">
    <div style="position: relative">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="content">
        <?php
        $post = get_post( 604 );
        echo $post->post_content;
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

After I do that, in PC screen it works fine, but in mobile screen the words doesn't wrap.
I don't know if it's related to wordpress adding `&nbsp;` instead of normal spacing, or maybe it's just CSS.

I have tried using `width: auto;` as you can see without any success.

How can I wrap words that features absolute position?

[Related link](https://nudaswim.com/about/)

Comment: You need to set an explicit width on your `.content` div. Absolute positioning removes the element from normal document flow.

Comment: @disinfor that doesn't work well, try doing that with inspect tool and you will see

Comment: I know how to position and size absolute positioned elements. Been doing this a long time. I think you can probably approach this differently. I'll create an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your `p` tags from your live URL and there are `&nbsp;` in the code, so I used `word-break` on the `p` tags. You may not have to if your code doesn't have them.

1. To get this to work better for you, add a percentage `width` to your `content` div and add an inner div for your content.
2. You don't need your empty `position: relative` div. Just make the section position relative
3. This will also scale responsively to mobile. Although you may consider changing how the `image` scales, since you have it set at `70vh` and if the text is longer, it will overflow past the image (as you can see in running the code snippet with going to full screen).

```css
#about {
  padding-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000');
  background-position: 50% 30%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  filter: brightness(80%);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  direction: rtl;
  width: 80%;
}

.content p {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner">
      <p class="has-text-align-center" data-fontsize="16">התשוקה הגדולה שלי לקיץ, לים ולחופשות אקזוטיות הביאו אותי לבחור לעסוק בעיצוב ותפירה של בגדי ים.</p>

      <p class="has-text-align-center" data-fontsize="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;בגדי&nbsp;הים&nbsp;שלנו&nbsp;מעוצבים&nbsp;בקפידה&nbsp;בדגש&nbsp;על&nbsp;גזרות&nbsp;נוחות&nbsp;ומחמיאות&nbsp;משמעות&nbsp;השם&nbsp;נודה&nbsp;מגיע&nbsp;מהשפה&nbsp;האיטלקית&nbsp;ופירושו&nbsp;'ערומה'.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

      <p class="has-text-align-center" data-fontsize="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;את&nbsp;כל&nbsp;תהליך&nbsp;הפיתוח&nbsp;(עיצוב,&nbsp;תפירה&nbsp;ומה&nbsp;שביניהם)&nbsp;אנחנו&nbsp;עושים&nbsp;בארץ,&nbsp;וגאים&nbsp;להיות&nbsp;100%&nbsp;כחול לבן.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Even better would be to move your image to the `section` tag and use `flex` to position the content.

1. The background image is now in the `::after` pseudo element.
2. Changing the `#about` section to a flex parent, we can center the `content` div horizontally and vertically.
3. The content div can now affect the `about` section so it can grow vertically, depending on the `content` div height.
4. Switch to `min-height:` on the `#about` section, so the `content`, if it gets longer, will not spill out.

```css
#about {
  padding-top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#about::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 30%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  direction: rtl;
  flex: 0 1 80%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.content p {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="content">
    <p class="has-text-align-center" data-fontsize="16">התשוקה הגדולה שלי לקיץ, לים ולחופשות אקזוטיות הביאו אותי לבחור לעסוק בעיצוב ותפירה של בגדי ים.</p>

    <p class="has-text-align-center" data-fontsize="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;בגדי&nbsp;הים&nbsp;שלנו&nbsp;מעוצבים&nbsp;בקפידה&nbsp;בדגש&nbsp;על&nbsp;גזרות&nbsp;נוחות&nbsp;ומחמיאות&nbsp;משמעות&nbsp;השם&nbsp;נודה&nbsp;מגיע&nbsp;מהשפה&nbsp;האיטלקית&nbsp;ופירושו&nbsp;'ערומה'.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>

    <p class="has-text-align-center" data-fontsize="16">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;את&nbsp;כל&nbsp;תהליך&nbsp;הפיתוח&nbsp;(עיצוב,&nbsp;תפירה&nbsp;ומה&nbsp;שביניהם)&nbsp;אנחנו&nbsp;עושים&nbsp;בארץ,&nbsp;וגאים&nbsp;להיות&nbsp;100%&nbsp;כחול לבן.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`word-break`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp).

Add this in your custom CSS.

```
.content {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

[image]

Comment: But now it's breaking the letters inside the word, I want only the words to be break not the letters.

Comment: sorry i cant understand this language thats why i couldn't notice. can you make it english for few minutes so i can preview?

Comment: or can you try `word-break: break-word;` let me know please